# Stop gcc from overwriting object files

Tags: c, gcc

```
gcc -c ./foo/name.c ./bar/name.c
```

This will output a single file ./name.o. I'm assuming one overwrites the other.

How can I get gcc to place the object files in the same directory as the source files, in order to prevent object files from overwriting each other?

EDIT:

For anyone wondering how to fix this in a Makefile.

```
SOURCES = /foo/name.c ./bar/name.c

build:
    $(foreach SOURCE,$(SOURCES), \
        gcc -c -o $(SOURCE:.c=.o) $(SOURCE);\
    )
```

Comment: [`-o <path/to/file>`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide into 2 commands.

```
gcc -c -o ./foo/name.o ./foo/name.c
gcc -c -o ./bar/name.o ./bar/name.c
```